# jquery validate and error styles

Tags: jquery, css, validation

[image]

how do i get rid of the borders in ul > li ?

i have :

```
    errorLabelContainer: $("ul", $('div.error')), wrapper: 'li',

errorContainer: $('div.error'),
```

i tried :

```
 div.message{
background: transparent url(images\ad_next.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
padding-left: 17px; border:0px;
}
div.message ul, li { border:0px; }
div.error{
    background-color:#F3E6E6;
    border-color: #924949;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: are you using Jörn Zaefferer's validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class="error" was declared in an included css. when i commented that out and used:

```
  div.error li { border:0px; }
```

it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
div.message li { border:0px; }
```

should be enough

Answer (score 0):

take a look at class="error", if you're looking at styling an error message from [Jörn Zaefferer validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

```
<label for="description" generated="true" class="error">error</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried this

```
var validator = $("#formId").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.css({border:"0px"});
            }
        });
```